# Equivalent of InstanceID and ANDROID_ID on iOS and Windows

Tags: android, ios, windows, uuid, instanceid

I am developing an Android app which makes use of the InstanceID token and ANDROID_ID.

I want to know if there is an equivalent of these in iOS and Windows environments?

If yes, I can use them (and its respective counterpart on iOS and Windows) for uniquely identifying the app installation.

Else, I will have to use something else available on all platforms like UUID.

Comment: there are multiple unique IDs you can get. we need more context of usage of this ID in order to suggest which one is better to be used.

Comment: @TungFam, I understand. I am looking for a unique ID to identify a device, as can be done by ANDROID_ID ( I am not bothered about the Android ID being same on all Galaxy Tab devices, as Google does not turn up any results regarding this bug over the last year), and a unique ID to identify app installation, as can be done by UUID and InstanceID both.